# freeCodeCamp Counting Cards

Tags: javascript

I am currently attempting the Javascript course in freeCodeCamp and want some feedback on my code for the Counting Cards exercise.

https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/counting-cards.

There are plenty of solutions available via google using switch statements, but few using if/else.  I am just wondering if my code is viable.

Thanks in advance.

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  var count=0;

 if (card>=2 && card<=6){          //cards 2,3,4,5,6
    count+=1;
 }else if (card>=7 && card<=9){      //cards 7,8,9
    count=count+=0;
 }else{                             //cards 10,'J','Q','K','A'
   count-=1;
 };
 return count;

 if (count>0){
   return count+'Bet';
 }else{
   return count+'Hold';
 };
 // Only change code above this line
 }


  // Add/remove calls to test your function.
  // Note: Only the last will display
  cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

Comment: Can't reach the last `if(count>0)` since you have a `return` before it

Comment: `count=count+=0;` thats a no op?

Comment: Your code would work fine, if you follow the instructions they said or at least understand the question, as they said you should not rest the count to 0, also remove return count as the function stops execution there and has a space before the test to match the criteria `­ Bet` not `Bet`

Answer (score 1):

1. no need add ';'after{}(in 'if'),
2. the function should return one value.you return two values by two 'if' in one function.
3. before function cc(),already define count's value,you re-define it in the function.when you run the 'cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');'.every time the count's value will be '0' in the function starting. that means you run 'cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');' is same to run 'cc('A');'.  so it display the wrong result.
4. there is no 'count=count+=0;' you should type 'count+=0;'

**here is the right code based in yours**

```
 var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
 if (card>=2 && card<=6){          //cards 2,3,4,5,6
    count+=1;
 }else if (card>=7 && card<=9){      //cards 7,8,9
    count+=0;
 }else  {                             //cards 10,'J','Q','K','A'
   count-=1;
 }
 return count<=0?count+" Hold":count+" Bet";
 // Only change code above this line
 }


  // Add/remove calls to test your function.
  // Note: Only the last will display
  cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```